# Livewire en Laravel 9 y Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream, laravel-9

Tengo un problema, como podria hacer que la vista generada por el componente de livewire no se muestre en el dashboard de jetstream?, sino una vista aparte como cualquier otra
[image]
la lista de nombre la estoy generando pero no logro hacer que se genera en una vista vacia ese es el problema no quiero la plantilla de jetstream por encima

```html
Route::get('users',ListUsers::class); asi esta desde mi web.php y mi clase: 

public function render() 
{ 
  $this->user = Users::all(); 
  return view('livewire.users'); 
} 
asi esta mi codigo , que parte debo modificar?
```

Comment: Debes crear un componente de livewire y en tus rutas pasar directamente el componente, dentro del componente en render pones la vista que deseas retornar

Comment: Route::get('users',ListUsers::class);  asi esta desde mi web.php y      mi clase:                                                                                                         public function render()
    {
        $this->user = Users::all();
        return view('livewire.users');
    }     asi esta mi codigo , que parte me sugieres cambiar?